# Single quotation with a number when getting the type of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, ienumerable, c#-8.0

I have an enumerable as follows:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObjectType> dataToImport;
```

At runtime I run the following code:

```
dataToImport.GetType().ToString()
```

So far so good. Checking results at runtime shows me something like the following :

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeObjectType]
```

Can somebody tell me what that **`1** means and where it is coming from? Should I expect this on all collections?

Answer (score 1):

It's a placeholder for the first generic type argument. You should expect it on anything with a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

The backtick(`) followed by a digit represent the number of generic arguments. For example `List<T>` has one generic argument hence `1